# Loading a UDF and a custom module in the same unit test instantiating an embedded database

Tags: java, junit, neo4j

I have two different test classes, one testing a module that I wrote and the other testing a user-defined function that I developed. These two tests instantiate a Neo4j for testing purposes differently. Module test does it like this:

```
class ModuleTest
{
    GraphDatabaseService database;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        String confFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("neo4j-module.conf").getPath();
        database = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder()
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(confFile)
                .newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

While the UDF test class instantiates its embedded database this way:

```
public class UdfTest
{
    @Rule
    public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
        .withFunction(Udf.class);

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Throwable
    {
        try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4j.boltURI() , Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig())) {
            Session session = driver.session();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that in the first form the UDFs are not registered and in the second the module. My question is; how can I start an embedded Neo4j database for my tests in which both my module and UDF is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how APOC Procedures loads procedures and functions within their test classes. They call a utility method during setUp():

```
public static void registerProcedure(GraphDatabaseService db, Class<?>...procedures) throws KernelException {
    Procedures proceduresService = ((GraphDatabaseAPI) db).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Procedures.class);
    for (Class<?> procedure : procedures) {
        proceduresService.registerProcedure(procedure);
        proceduresService.registerFunction(procedure);
    }
}
```

Just pass the GraphDatabaseService and the Class with the procedures/functions to register, and this should set everything up for your test class.